# How to generate 4 digit cryptography random number using Python

Tags: python, random

I am generating the 4 digit random number using Python but I need to include make it cryptographically. My code is below:

```
range_start = 10 ** (4 - 1)
range_end = (10 ** 4) - 1
password = randint(range_start, range_end)
```

Here I am generating the 4 digit random number but it does not include any cryptography and I need to make it cryptographically random number.

Comment: I have no idea either. A reminder, there's uuid `str(uuid.uuid4().int>>64)[0:4]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're generating a *pin code*, in Python 3.6, use `n = secrets.choice(range(1000, 10000))`; then `format(n, '04')` and then filter out unwanted combinations.

If you're stuck with Python 2, the `random.SystemRandom` will generate cryptographically more secure random numbers; use

```
from random import SystemRandom
sr = SystemRandom()
n = sr.choice(xrange(1000, 10000))
pin = format(n, '04')
print(pin)
```

With `choice` you can also prefilter the pincodes:

```
all_pins = [format(i, '04') for i in range(1000, 10000)]
possible = [i for i in all_pins if len(set(i)) > 1]
```

would filter out those whose *set of digits* has just one member (i.e. consist of just repeated one digit), for example.

Comment: I am using the python version 2.7.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yeah it works, I just teach them `choice` so that next time they don't say "then how about choose from a sequence"